# Sending a file from desktop app to iPad via iTunes using scripting bridge

Tags: ios, ipad, itunes, file-sharing, scripting-bridge

I want to find out if it's possible to automate a process of exporting (a zip) from a desktop app into an app on the iPad via file sharing in iTunes. The most likely technique I've found is by scripting Bridge.

Answer (score 0):

Did you took a look at [libimobiledevice](http://www.libimobiledevice.org/)?
This would make your desktop app really flexible. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe iTunes exposes scriptability for file sharing, so Scripting Bridge won't be much help.